# Complex Date Predicate Usage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to filter my results based on records between the greatest date in my table and the 20 day window prior to the greatest date.

I've come up with the following code:-

```
SELECT orderid, custid, empid, shipperid, orderdate, filler
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE orderid BETWEEN min(max(orderdate)-DATEADD(day,20,orderdate)) AND max(orderdate)
order by orderid
```

This generates the following error:-

```
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 226
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

I can't understand why. Please could somebody let me know why I am getting this error and also suggest a way I could go about achieving my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use aggregation functions in the `where` clause.  Probably the best way to do this is by putting the logic in the `from`:

```
select o.*
from dbo.Orders o cross join
     (select max(orderdate) as maxorderdate from orders) omax
where o.orderdate between dateadd(day, -20, omax.maxorderdate) and omax.maxorderdate
order by orderid;
```

EDIT:

An alternative method is:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*, max(orderdate) over () as maxorderdate
      from dbo.orders o
     ) o
where orderdate between dateadd(day, -20, maxorderdate) and maxorderdate
order by orderid;
```

The previous version might be more efficient, but it is worth testing the two versions.

Comment: Why do you think this would be better than using a CTE?

Comment: @Hogan . . . In terms of performance, they should be the same.

Comment: That is what I thought too, but you said "Probably the best way..." so I was hoping to learn something new.

Comment: Could I ask, why a cross join?

Comment: @BubbleandSqueak cross join there is almost stylistic if he just said join it would do the same.  Since there is only one item in the sub query it will add that one item to every row -- as a cross join or as a join.

Comment: @BubbleandSqueak . . . As opposed to what?  I never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Explicit `JOIN` syntax is always clearer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff As opposed to inner join I mean

Comment: @BubbleandSqueak . . . Yes, it could also be written with a `join`.  I guess when a subquery returns a single row, my inclination is to use `cross join`.